# AttributeError: __enter__ in pyopenssl 20.0.1

Tags: websocket, openssl, python-3.7, wss, pyopenssl

When creating a secure websocket connection(wss) using websocket create_connection() api call in pyopenssl - openssl/ssl.py (20.0.1), **AttributeError: **enter**** error is thrown.

Error is pointing to "with statements available in send method of SSL.py file"  whereas in 19.1.0 pyopenssl version, there was no error observed.

```
with _from_buffer(buf) as data:
            # check len(buf) instead of len(data) for testability
            if len(buf) > 2147483647:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Cannot send more than 2**31-1 bytes at once."
                )

            result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, data, len(data))
            self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)

            return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `pip install pyOpenSSL==19.1.0`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it